# How to share access to protractor.ExpectedConditions

Tags: typescript, protractor

In all of my page objects I am doing

```
import { browser, ElementFinder, $, protractor } from 'protractor';

const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

export class MyPageObject { }
```

Is there a way to share the expected conditions object?

Comment: `export const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;` ?

Comment: you could also just import ExpectedConditions. `import {ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';` Although reading your question, I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for? Are you asking to remove the one line of code `const EC`? Are you trying to export the same EC reference to all page objects?

Comment: Trying to export the same EC reference to all page objects.

Comment: Just import it. Also you could do `import {ExpectedConditions as EC} from 'protractor';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a global variable on the `onPrepare()` method:

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    onPrepare: function () {
        global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    }
};
```

Comment: ExpectedConditions is already `global`. So you are basically setting `global.EC = global.ExpectedConditions`. I'm not sure why this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

ExpectedConditions is readily available as an import object. I have concerns about setting EC globally. See comment above. This should just be:

```
import {ExpectedConditions as EC} from 'protractor';

// use EC as is without setting it globally.
export class MyPageObject { }
```